# MvvmCross: `nameof()` vs. expression source binding performance

Tags: performance, mvvm, binding, expression, mvvmcross

Which is faster to create and/or apply?

`set.Bind(...).For(...).To(vm => vm.PropertyName)`

or

`set.Bind(...).For(...).To(nameof(TViewModel.PropertyName))`

?

Comment: nameof()-Operator is replaced with the name of the property as string during compilation. So during runtime it is To("PropertyName"). This is some sort of microoptimization. Use the language features that you are more familiar with. Both statements support renaming and refactoring scenarios

Comment: Yes, I understand how nameof works. However, I was wondering if using one vs. another was slightly faster. 

(I understand that in most scenarios I should not really care, but still)

Comment: I believe it ultimately boils down to the same code. The expression syntax will eventually get the name of the property as a string. So at the lowest level, it still uses strings and reflection. `nameof` is useful in situations where there is no expression-based alternative. So I think it's a matter of personal preference.